# Sorting a list based on another list with DSU

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.1

For a class project, I need to use python 2.1, and I'll probably have to use DSU for sorting, which I'm not familiar with. So I'd like some help if possible.

I have a list for storing vertexes and their coordinates. for example

```
vertex = [(2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1)]
```

and so on.

I also have another list which will store the index positions of the vertex, sorted according to their first coordinate.
So it will start like this

```
order = [0, 1, 2]
```

And my objective is for it to be like this, considering the example

```
order = [2, 0, 1]
```

without changing the order in the list "vertex".

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: waht will be your expected output??

Comment: @Hackaholic the output is the list 'order' sorted, based on the first element in each tuple in the list 'vertex'. so in the example above, the list 'order' shows the order of the vertexes, from the lowest first coordinate to the largest first coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it works in Python2.1, but either of the following does what you ask in Python2.7:

```
order = [i for i,_ in sorted(enumerate(vertex), key = lambda x: x[1])]
```

or

```
order = [0,1 ,2]
order.sort(key=lambda x: vertex[x])
```

---

This probably works in Python2.1 (I don't have Python 2.1 installed to test it).

```
order.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(vertex[x],vertex[y]))
```

Comment: I was forced to use 2.1 because we need to use a tool that a former student coded, and it wasn't tested after 2.1. Good thing is that, apparently, it works with 2.7 with little to no tweaking, so you answer works.
And thanks for even taking your time trying to do a 2.1 version of the answer. Really appreciate it :)